# Undefined variable in php

Tags: php, variables

Hello I have an error script I don't know for why but the variable is defined:

```
 public function Updates($user_ids,$lastid) {
    if($lastid==0)  {
        $loadmore = "";     
    }else{
        $loadmore = " AND M.msg_id < $lastid ";
    }

 public function Total_Updates($user_ids) 

{

$sql = "SELECT M.msg_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.created, U.fname, U.lname, M.uploads, M.profile_uid FROM messages M, users U WHERE M.uid_fk=U.uid AND M.uid_fk IN ($user_ids) $loadmore
        UNION
        SELECT M.msg_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.created, U.fname, U.lname, M.uploads, M.profile_uid FROM messages M, users U WHERE M.uid_fk=U.uid AND M.profile_uid IN ($user_ids) $loadmore ORDER BY msg_id DESC ";

        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        $data = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        exit();

    return $data;

}
```

The variable that undefined is located in the same line as the SELECT..
I am waiting your help... Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 lines with SELECT, however both having the same variables: $user_ids and $loadmore

The error message should show what it is warning about. but $user_ids looks declared correctly so that leaves $loadmore.

It also looks the `function Total_Updates` is inside `function Updates` ?

if it is a separate function (and just a copy paste error?) you would probably just want to use `global $loadmore;` in the beginning of both functions.

**Edit:**
Possible changes to Code to use global. With this function `Updates`, always needs to be called before `Total_Updates`.

```
public function Updates($user_ids, $lastid) 
{
    global $loadmore; // Keep available for Total_Updates

    if($lastid==0)  {
        $loadmore = "";     
    }else{
        $loadmore = " AND M.msg_id < $lastid ";
    }
    $db_conx = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
    $sql = "SELECT M.msg_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.created, U.fname, U.lname, M.uploads, M.profile_uid FROM messages M, users U  WHERE M.uid_fk=U.uid AND M.uid_fk IN ($user_ids) $loadmore
            UNION 
            SELECT M.msg_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.created, U.fname, U.lname, M.uploads, M.profile_uid FROM messages M, users U  WHERE M.uid_fk=U.uid AND M.profile_uid IN ($user_ids) $loadmore ORDER BY msg_id DESC LIMIT " .$this->postcount;
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);      

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $data[]=$row;
        return $data;
    }
}

public function Total_Updates($user_ids) 
{
    global $loadmore; // From Updates

    $db_conx = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

    $sql = "SELECT M.msg_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.created, U.fname, U.lname, M.uploads, M.profile_uid FROM messages M, users U WHERE M.uid_fk=U.uid AND M.uid_fk IN ($user_ids) $loadmore
            UNION
            SELECT M.msg_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.created, U.fname, U.lname, M.uploads, M.profile_uid FROM messages M, users U WHERE M.uid_fk=U.uid AND M.profile_uid IN ($user_ids) $loadmore ORDER BY msg_id DESC ";

    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $data = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    exit();  // This is just for test? it disables return.
    return $data;       
}
```

An alternate solution would be to create a separate function for loadmore ex:

```
public function getUpdates_loadmore($lastid) 
{
    if($lastid==0)  return "";
    return " AND M.msg_id < $lastid ";
}
```

And do `$loadmore = getUpdates_loadmore($lastid);` for this the $lastid parameter would need to be added to `function Total_Updates($user_ids)` => `function Total_Updates($user_ids, $lastid)`

Answer (score 0):

In fact, my scripts looks exactly like it :

```
public function Updates($user_ids,$lastid) 
{
if($lastid==0)  {
    $loadmore = "";     
}else{
    $loadmore = " AND M.msg_id < $lastid ";
}
    $db_conx = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
    $sql = "SELECT M.msg_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.created, U.fname, U.lname, M.uploads, M.profile_uid FROM messages M, users U  WHERE M.uid_fk=U.uid AND M.uid_fk IN ($user_ids) $loadmore
            UNION 
            SELECT M.msg_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.created, U.fname, U.lname, M.uploads, M.profile_uid FROM messages M, users U  WHERE M.uid_fk=U.uid AND M.profile_uid IN ($user_ids) $loadmore ORDER BY msg_id DESC LIMIT " .$this->postcount;
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);      

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $data[]=$row;
    return $data;
    }
}           
  public function Total_Updates($user_ids) 

{

        $db_conx = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

$sql = "SELECT M.msg_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.created, U.fname, U.lname, M.uploads, M.profile_uid FROM messages M, users U WHERE M.uid_fk=U.uid AND M.uid_fk IN ($user_ids) $loadmore
        UNION
        SELECT M.msg_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.created, U.fname, U.lname, M.uploads, M.profile_uid FROM messages M, users U WHERE M.uid_fk=U.uid AND M.profile_uid IN ($user_ids) $loadmore ORDER BY msg_id DESC ";

        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        $data = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        exit();
    return $data;       
}
```

In the first $sql the variable $loadmore runs correctly but in the second $sql it does not work. I have always the same errors:

`Notice: Undefined variable`

Comment: You should update your question to reflect this instead of adding an Answer  
In your `function Total_Updates` `$loadmore` is not defined. If you call these functions after one another you could use `global` as described in my answer.

Comment: thank you very much NiKiZe your proposition runs perfectly...